# reasons for using SNMP for .net applications/services

Tags: .net, snmp

Work is considering using SNMP trap in our .net applications (windows servies), which are .net based.

Just trying to get feedback on this and whether its a food idea or if another monitoring means is better.

thanks

Comment: At least SNMP is an open standard. To use it or not, you need to review the requirements, which you did not describe a little in your question. That makes it impossible for anyone else to know what you are doing.

Comment: Those are pretty much the requirements I've been given. OPS wants DEV to provide SNMP Traps in our web apps so they can use it however they like.

My question to the community is whether this is a good idea in general or whether OPS doesn't know any better. I don't know anything about SNMP which is why I'm asking the question. Is there a better approach?